# Python Logic conflict with sending data to a list of clients

Tags: python, sockets

**Problem:** Server sends data to the latest client only.

**Explanation:**

I've got a list called `User_list`. This list contains two types of information: A connection, and a username as an attribute of each connection.

If somebody connects, the server receives a username, checks if that username is in it's list, and upon finding it is not, sends everybody the entire list of usernames with the latest one added. Except it only seems to send it to the very latest client.

Here's a [slideshow](http://s1267.photobucket.com/user/owatch/slideshow/Server%20Issue) of the events that occur. (The Command prompt's are the clients)

I also thought I'd add the server code here on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wGtuTb7M):

```
# Owatch's Multi-Threading Username Sever. (Because the select module can suck it)
from socket import *
import threading
import os
import csv
import sys
# Defining Important Information
User_List = []
Connections_List = []
# Making a thread class for each connection recieved.
class Client(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,conn):
        super(Client, self).__init__()
        self.conn = conn
        self.username = self.conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not any(user.username == self.username for user in User_List):
            print("New guy")
            # Add new guy to the list
            User_List.append(self)

            # Get everyone's names
            current_userlist = [user.username for user in User_List]

            # Send everyone's names to everyone
            for x in User_List:

                    conn.send(x.username.encode())  #  <---   Key line to the problem


U_HOST = input("Host: ")
U_PORT = input("Port: ")

SS = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
SS.bind((U_HOST,int(U_PORT)))
SS.listen(2)


while True:
    Connection,Address = SS.accept()
    Connections_List.append(Address)
    print("Connection Taken, and address added to list")
    CX = Client(Connection)
    CX.start()
```

Here's the [Client](http://pastebin.com/w1GHUgnK) as well if you want to tinker with it:

```
from socket import *
import threading
import os
import csv

Username = ("Owatch")
# ^^  Change Username to make a new Client!!

host = input("Host: ")
port = input("Port: ")
try:
    ss = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    ss.connect((host,int(port)))
except IOError:
    print("Console: Error Encountered During Username Accuasition")

ss.send(Username.encode())
print("\n Username Sent...")
while True:
    try:
        print("\nWaiting to Recieve Data")
        data = ss.recv(1024)
        if data:
            translated_data = data.decode()
            print(translated_data)
            if translated_data == Username:
                print("It's one of ours!")

            else:
                Client_Username = translated_data
                print ("Foreign Username is set to be: ", Client_Username)


    except Exception as e:
        print (vars(e))
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So where is the part that sends every user name to every client? I can see only one loop and it iterates over the list of clients and sends each name through `conn`, which is the connection of the last joined client.

Comment: Well, that is the intent. I'm not so good with my code, so that's why I am asking help. As far as I know: for x in User_list means for every element of User_List [connection + attributed username] conn.send (The connection element of the element x for x in User_List.send(the username).

Comment: So It's supposed to send to each conn attibute of the elements in the list the username. Except as I see it, since conn = self.conn. That's where the problem stems from but I can't seem to get farther than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can tell from your comment that you realise that

```
conn == self.conn
```

If you want to send something to a user `x` you, of course, have to do

```
x.conn.send(something)
```

Now, if in your loop you do

```
for x in User_List:
    x.conn.send(x.username.encode())
```

this will send each user his own name.

You want to send every name to every user. Again. *Every name* should be sent to *every user*. That's two loops. You'll need one loop to iterate over user connections and enother loop to send him all the names.

```
for x in User_List:
    for y in User_List:
        x.conn.send(y.username.encode())
```

*Also you might want to read [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).*

Comment: Y is not defined. Error

Comment: Is it supposed to be y.username.encode() ? I keep getting an error because y is not defined.

Comment: @Xeon oh, sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Fixed. I feel stupid I don't quite get it myself. (I understand the logic, but not how the code represents it) (Also, I never thought you could stack for x and for y like that. Thanks so much man.